# anticipating a click event within a while loop - jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a little dice game app with javascript/jquery and the part where I run into trouble is in the following while loop.  I want the user to click the button and then the body of the while loop should execute.  However, with the following code, the contents of the while loop execute without waiting for the user to click each time.  Is this the right way to approach what I'm trying to do?

```
            while (dice.value != rollFirst && dice.value != 7)
            {
                $("#roll").click(function()
                {
                    $("#roll").unbind('click');
                    dice.roll();
                });
```

update:  Based on the responses, maybe I wasn't totally clear in what I'm trying to do.  For every iteration of the while loop, I want to user to click the roll button and only then do I want to continue execution of the contents of the while loop.  In other words, I want the while loop to wait until the users clicks "roll" for each iteration.

As it is right now, the logic of the program works but it doesn't wait for the user to click the roll button.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear. Putting the `while` loop inside your `click` handler seems to be a logical workaround, but it depends on what you're trying to do. Please provide more context.

Comment: That's simply going to bind a `click` event handler to the element with the id `roll` repeatedly until the condition returns `false`, which doesn't seem like it's what you'd want. If you state the overall problem, it may be easier to spot the best approach.

Comment: I added some more details.  Hopefully that will explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `while` loop to run inside a `click` event handler then the code must be located within that event handler:

```
$("#roll").one(function() {
    dice.roll();
    while (dice.value != rollFirst && dice.value != 7) {}
});
```

If you want to roll the dice until the `while` loop argument becomes true then:

```
$("#roll").one(function() {
    while (dice.value != rollFirst && dice.value != 7) {
        dice.roll();
    }
});
```

Notice the use of `.one()` which will only run the `click` event handler for the `#roll` element once.

- `.one()`: http://api.jquery.com/one

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$("#roll").click(function() {
    $("#roll").unbind("click");

    while (dice.value != rollFirst && dice.value != 7) {
        dice.roll();
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of unbinding the event yourself, create a [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You put your click binding inside you loop which is wrong and will cause an issue. You need to put your logic inside your Click event. Something like:

```
$("#roll").click(function()
{
     while (dice.value != rollFirst && dice.value != 7)
     {
         $("#roll").unbind('click');
         dice.roll();
         break;
     }
});
```